# How could you create a "content_for" equivalent in PHP?

Tags: php, content-for

I've been working on a small page in PHP, one that doesn't need the power of a full-fledged framework behind it. One thing that I'm really missing from previous work in Ruby-on-Rails is the ability to effectively pass content up the page using "content_for".

What I was wondering is, how could you create a page lifecycle that would accomplish this same effect in PHP?

So, here's a simple example:

Let's say you have a template that defines an index page, just a recurring header and menu you want to use on all your pages. So your `index.php` file looks basically like this:

```
...header stuff...
<body>
<?php include $file.'.php'; ?>
</body>
...footer stuff...
```

EDIT: Thanks for the tips on URL security, but let's just assume I'm getting the user request safely :)

Now, lets say in the header you want to put this:

```
<head>
<title><?php echo $page_title; ?></title>
</head>
```

It would be nice to be able to specify the title in the included file, so at the url `http://example.com/index.php?p=test` you're loading `test.php`, and that file looks like this:

```
<?php $page_title = 'Test Page'; ?>
... rest of content ...
```

Now, obviously this doesn't work, because the including page (index.php) is loaded before the variable is set.

In Rails this is where you could pass stuff 'up the page' using the `content_for` function.

**My question is this: What would be the simplest, leanest way that you all can think of to effect this kind of 'content_for' functionality in PHP?**

Ideally I'd like suggestions that don't involve strapping on some big framework, but some relatively light boilerplate code that could be used in a lot of different applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Never** do `include $_GET['p']`. This opens a huge security hole in your site, as include accepts filenames and URLs, so anybody would be able to read any file on your site and also execute any code on your server. You may want to check and sanitize the value first.
2. If you need something simple, you may put header and footer in separate files, execute your `test.php` which would set the variables, capture its output using [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), then include the header, output the middle part and include the footer. Example:

   ```
    <?php ob_start(); ?>
    <body>
    <?php include $filename.'.php'; ?>
    </body>
    <?php $content = ob_get_clean(); 
     include 'header.php';
     echo $content;
     include 'footer.php';
     ?>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on $_GET, I was really trying just to quickly give a wireframe example, but you made a very good point. Regarding Output Buffering, I'm not familiar with that. I'll look through the docs shortly, but is it simple enough that you could give an example snippet? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, after testing this out, this method works beautifully. Thank you very much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly (I have not used RoR extensively), you could put your data in a variable or a function. If your content was in a variable, your "test.php" could simply hold all your variables and you could load it at the very beginning of your index file (likewise for a function depending on how complicated your needs are; if you're doing a lot of extra work, you may need to use a function as a variable won't work).

For example, your test.php would look something like this:

```
<?php
$page_title = "Test Page";
$page_content = "Some sort of content";

// Or

function page_content()
{
    // Run some functions and print content at the end
}

?>
```

Then, in your index.php

```
<?php include $_GET['p'].'.php'; ?>
...header stuff...
<title><?php print $page_title; ?></title>
<body>
<?php print $page_content; ?>
<!-- OR if function -->
<?php page_content(); ?>
</body>
...footer stuff...
```

This way everything should load properly. You could also split things up, but that would complicate your structure (especially if there is no need for an elaborate framework, this would be unnecessary).

Good luck!
Dennis M.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I thought of this a bit... the downside to me seems that the content is going to be HTML, possibly complex HTML. Now, I could use heredoc syntax and save it all as a really long string I guess, but that seems like it would make typing clunky since I'd lose syntax highlighting in the entire page. Still, a viable suggestion, thanks! I'll hang on for a few more before I select an answer.

Comment: If you use $page_content = <<<EOD you shouldn't have any syntax highlighting issues. If it effects your IDE simply insert this after you finish page editing. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Are you worried about XSS? Or are you going to filter/whitelist the "filenames" from the query string?

My answer would be to use mod_rewrite -- if you're using PHP, you're likely using Apache!

You could filter out files with a RewriteCond and your RewriteRule could be:

RewriteRule /index.php?p=(.*)$  $1 [L,QSA]

This may be a different approach than the PHP functionality you were looking for, but it comes to mind...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question so that I'm not demonstrating a security hole. Do you have any suggestions for implementing the `content_for` functionality?